# What is a good English translation of 相见亦无事，别后常忆君。

Tags: translation

I see this sentence in a question about friendship, and I like this answer the most, who can give me a good English translation.

Thank you.

Comment: question should not be  merely contained in headline

Answer (score 3):

Growth in longing comes from a place of absence

Answer (score 0):

Literally:

When we are together, there is nothing special, but once we part from each other, I miss you day and day.

Comment: Is there any poem in English has the same meaning?

Comment: Um... I think this just happened to me two months ago...

Answer (score 0):

相见亦无事，别后常忆君。

When we're together, it just seems so natural, when we're apart, I can't stop thinking of you.